# Post updating from jdk8 to jdk 11, getting powermock and mockito dependency issues

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, java-11

Post updating from jdk8 to jdk 11, getting powermock and mockito dependency issues. I have changed dependency versions to latest available as below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And now a number of my junits are failing for different issues. I want to avoid modifying all junits.
What are the compitable versions for powermock-module-junit4, powermock-api-mockito and mockito-core to be used with jdk11 ?

Comment: asking the compatibility here is not really a good idea, if you could rather post the errors that you see trying to solve one at a time, people out there might explain what's the resolution they have tried. have you modularised(java module) your applications to start off with?

Comment: There are around 90-100 different errors, for that reason I havent posted the errors. Looking to find the compatible versions for dependencies so as to make least changes to existing junits.